# I couldn't define "GetProperties" to other class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, debugging, c#-4.0

This is the class I use to format the values:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace tempo
{
    public class Hayvan
    {
        public string name;
        public int weight;
        public int length;

        public string GetProperties()
        {
            return String.Format("Name:{0}, Weight:{1}, Length:{2}", name, weight, length);
        }
    }
}
```

This one is the error I get in program.cs when I try to call the method:

```
using System;

namespace tempo
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Inheritance (KALITIM)

            Kedi kedi = new Kedi() { weight = 3, length = 5, name = "Kobe" };
            Console.WriteLine(kedi.GetProperties);
        }
    }
```

It gives me error at getProperties in program.cs
How can I fix this?

Comment: 1. Please post your code into the question **as text**, not **as image**. 2. How is `Kedi` related to `Hayvan`?

Comment: What does this have ti do with Unity3d ?

Comment: Kedi is the name of the class, kedi is the reference to the object, try using kedi.method name

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the () after the method called, if this doesn't fix it, continue to follow the comment
Seems like you are creating a variable of type `Kedi` and then you try from that to use a method from the class hayvan, you should try something like this:
Inside Program.cs:

```
Hayvan test = new Hayvan() { //Insert eventual values };
Console.WriteLine(test.GetProperties());
```

But before doing that create an empty contructor inside Hayvan using the ctor shortcut or manually, let me know if this will fit it
P.S: Next time add the code using a codeBlock from the editor instead of an image, so we can copy and test ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The bottom image shows `kedi.GetProperties`, but the top images shows the definition of `GetProperties()` on the `Hayvan` class.
If the definition of `GetProperties()` is the same on `Kedi` as it is on `Hayvan` then you will need to make the definition `static` to access it in the way you have.